# WatchkitUpload Issues

Tags: objective-c, app-store, watchkit

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "xxx Mobile". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

Invalid WatchKit Support - The WatchKitSupport2 folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.

Invalid Executable - The executable '***.app/Watch/watchkitapp.app/PlugIns/watchkitapp Extension.appex/watchkitapp Extension' does not contain bitcode.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this error?

Comment: i am getting exactly same error...did u get any solutions for it? please respond if u got any solution..

Answer (score 0):

[image]For second issue you need to enable bitcode for your app target as its required for watch apps.

Select your iOS app target- > Build Settings - > Build Options - > Enable Bitcode

Set it to true.

[Refer this for App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html)

Comment: The WatchKit target neither the extension have the enable bitcode option in build settings , any other solution.

Comment: I am using Xcode 8.3 and its there. see image for reference

Comment: Agree but have to buiild by latest Xcode as per the security norms and apple standard to stop using old Xcode , any other inputs

Comment: Bitcode options is available for  App target not for watchapp or extension. This is also mentioned in answer. App target means your iphone app target. You have to enable it in that

Comment: So how to resolve the problem as I’ve disable the option in main app target to no bitcode and my app is uploaded successful later iTunes connect email sends error

Comment: So does that mean that I have to enable bitcode to main app target and all targets which have it coz I have Siri , SiriUI, WatchKit, WatchKit extension, widget, iMessage targets all in one app

Comment: you have to enable in the target that you are going to archive or make ipa for.

Comment: But that I did like main target enabled bitcode but still get Apple rejection

Comment: enable bitcode for all ? main project and all targets as I have Siri , SiriUI, WatchKit, WatchKit extension, iMessage @VickyDhas how did u resolve ?